# 100 % vested retirement benefits?

Tags: benefits

I worked for a school bus manufacturer for 13 years and my job was eliminated, I received severance package $5,000 and I had 401K which was rolled over to a money market account.  I was 100% vested and I was wondering can I receive retirement benefits from this company, now that I'm 55 years old.?

Comment: Did the manufacturer have a pension plan beyond the 401k?

Comment: Do you mean the 401K was rolled over to a money market account in an IRA?

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, I am not sure what you mean by stating that your 401K was rolled over to a money market account.
Assuming that it was rolled over to an IRA account, you can roll it over to another IRA account with a financial institution of your choice (either a brokerage or a bank.)
Alternatively, you can withdraw these funds, but since you are under 59.5 years old, you would have to cough up 10% penalty to IRS for this unqualified withdrawal. Therefore, I would strongly recommend for you to wait till you reach this eligible age. Other qualified (penalty-free) withdrawals are: purchase of the first home, college tuition, medical insurance premiums for unemployed individuals, disability, and medical expenses exceeding 7.5% of your Adjusted Gross Income.
I would assume that your 401K was a Traditional 401K account (before tax contributions), and not ROTH 401K, so yo would also have to pay taxes upon withdrawing funds whether you do it now or after you are 59.5 y.o.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "receive retirement benefits". If the company had a 401k, that probably is the retirement plan. Few companies have both a 401k and an old-style pension plan, you typically have one or the other. So if your 401k was rolled over into some other account, you have already received your retirement benefits.

If you mean that the 401k was rolled over into an IRA and you are asking if you can now start withdrawing from the IRA, see Excel Strategies answer. Short answer: Yes you can, but there's a 10% penalty unless you meet one of the exceptions.